# disable viewport zooming iOS 10+ safari?

Tags: mobile-safari, ios10, ios11, viewport, ios12

I've update my iPhone 6 plus to iOS 10 beta version and just found that in mobile safari, you can zoom any webpages by double tapping or pinching **IGNORE** the `user-scalable=no` code in the meta tag. I don't know whether it's a bug or feature. If it's considered as a feature, how do we disable viewport zooming iOS 10 safari ?

---

updated on iOS 11/12 release, iOS 11 and iOS 12 safari still DO **NOT** respect the `user-scalable=no` meta tag.

[image: mobile github site on Safari]

Comment: An accessibility feature: Of note in Safari on iOS 10 http://twitter.com/thomasfuchs/status/742531231007559680/photo/1

Comment: No, it isn't.  It is bad practice for normal web content.  For web apps, the default zoom behavior can completely ruin usability.  For example, nobody wants to zoom in on a channel up button because they tapped it twice, nor zoom in on part of a video game because they tapped the jump button twice.  There's a reason that this feature was added in the first place, and it makes no sense to break usability for everybody just because a few "web designers" don't know what they're doing.  Go scream at the site designers and quit breaking the browser.

Comment: Saying it's "bad practice" is an opinion and doesn't change the fact that Apple is insistent on taking web standards that the community spends months/years/decades getting implemented cross platform and taking a giant crap on them. Why should Apple dictate that web designers don't know what they're doing? Terrible argument.

Comment: Personally, I think this stems from boilerplate code online where devs just copy and paste blindly without knowing what the purpose of the code is.

Comment: Answer is simple, Apple: make disabling the meta tag a default-off accessibility setting. Those who need it, will have it, without punishing those who don't.

Comment: Have a look at my answer at the bottom of this page - my solution is a mix of other answers and my own invention.

Comment: Can someone confirm that none of the answers works on iOS 11 anymore?

Comment: I can confirm that its not working in iOS 12 ... sadly.

Comment: Apple shames the developer for not being accessible yet uses the tiniest font for everything. And if you use the accessibility features built into the os like making the font bigger it breaks the layout and sometimes even functionality. Such A-holes. I think it has more to do with trying to destroy web apps to force people into building apps they serve people through the apple store. Apple is the new Microsoft, remember IE6 - IE8.

Answer (score 107):

It's possible to prevent webpage scaling in safari on iOS 10, but it's going to involve more work on your part. I guess the argument is that a degree of difficulty should stop cargo-cult devs from dropping "user-scalable=no" into every viewport tag and making things needlessly difficult for vision-impaired users.

Still, I would like to see Apple change their implementation so that there is a simple (meta-tag) way to disable double-tap-to-zoom. Most of the difficulties relate to that interaction.

You can stop pinch-to-zoom with something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
  if (event.scale !== 1) { event.preventDefault(); }
}, false);
```

Note that if any deeper targets call stopPropagation on the event, the event will not reach the document and the scaling behavior will not be prevented by this listener.

Disabling double-tap-to-zoom is similar. You disable any tap on the document occurring within 300 milliseconds of the prior tap:

```
var lastTouchEnd = 0;
document.addEventListener('touchend', function (event) {
  var now = (new Date()).getTime();
  if (now - lastTouchEnd <= 300) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  lastTouchEnd = now;
}, false);
```

If you don't set up your form elements right, focusing on an input will auto-zoom, and since you have mostly disabled manual zoom, it will now be almost impossible to unzoom. Make sure the input font size is >= 16px.

If you're trying to solve this in a WKWebView in a native app, the solution given above is viable, but this is a better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31943976/661418. And as mentioned in other answers, in iOS 10 beta 6, Apple has now provided a flag to honor the meta tag.

**Update May 2017:** I replaced the old 'check touches length on touchstart' method of disabling pinch-zoom with a simpler 'check event.scale on touchmove' approach. Should be more reliable for everyone.

Comment: Note that touchstart hack is inconsistent... and if you manage to sidestep it you are stuck in a very uncomfortable state

Comment: I agree with @Joseph regarding the statement that Apple should reconsider/allow developers to bypass this for interactive mobile web experiences that don't even benefit from zooming in any capacity.

Comment: Eg. full screen mapping apps, there is a zoom feature hard coded in the mapping application (Google Maps JS, Leaflet etc.). Google advices to add a meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />` and if browser doesn't respect the meta tag, it is very bad browser design. The other this like very bad design is back/forward action by sliding, which cannot be prevented in iOS 9/10. It breaks severely dragging actions inside web application.

Comment: Both hacks do not work with iOS 10.1.1 when double-tapping or pinch-zooming an image. They prevent these actions happening on text, but images seem to be excluded?

Comment: If user start dragging with one finger then put a second finger on the screen will be able to pinch-zoom. You can disable both zoom and scroll with a `preventDefault` on `touchmove`. You can't (completely) disable zoom without disabling scroll.

Comment: Wow, this part (I'll paste here) was SUPER helpful to me. I haven't seen this mentioned by anyone else ANYWHERE on the internet. It took me hours to fix this problem. I'm really disappointed in Apple's UX design choices about this, where forms auto-zoom-in but then don't zoom back out. `If you don't set up your form elements right, focusing on an input will auto-zoom, and since you have mostly disabled manual zoom, it will now be almost impossible to unzoom. Make sure the input font size is >= 16px.`

Comment: Thanks, It is helpful for me.

Comment: This is what finally disabled the double-tap zoom for me. Although, I found with the 300ms span, a slower double-tap would still register. Increasing the gap to 500ms worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Can you point me to the MDN doc that describes `event.scale`. I'm using typescript and I can't resolve the event type.  I have found https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GestureEvent but it's marked as a non-standard API.

Comment: @Stewart Yeah, it's iOS-specific. But so is this question.

Comment: Why don't you use `gesturestart` instead touchmove with if clause? You would safe performance by not having a if clause, or is there any reason to do so?

Comment: The only problem is pinch zoom works while scrolling: To reproduce scroll slightly with one finger and then pinch with the other -> Zoom works and preventDefault() has no effect.

Comment: It seems that this isnt working in iOS 12 anymore. Any idea how to make this work for iOS 12?

Comment: I am certain it would have been a lot less code for apple to just add a switch in safari or accessibility settings that overrides the user-scalable meta tag, which would much more truly improve accessibility. They should also have a switch to turn off zoom and double-tap to zoom for folks who have parkinsons. We should all be shaming apple for using accessibility as a reason to push more people into apps only "accessible" in their web store. They don't really give a rats @ss about anything but profit.

Comment: Note that if you ever want to remove this event listener (e.g. you disable default behavior only for a temporal interaction), you also have to pass `false` (or `{ capture: true }`) as the last argument to `removeEventListener`: `document.removeEventListener('touchmove', yourFunction, false)`.
Struggled with this for a bit myself as page stopped scaling and scrolling forever after one interaction

Comment: Setting the font size to 16px was the fix for me

Comment: iOS 13 change false to {passive: false}

Comment: The `event.scale` bit works for me on iOS, but it prevents any & all panning on Android/Chrome v91. To make it work across these platforms I had to add `if (('scale' in event) && event.scale !== 1) { ...`

Answer (score 86):

This is a new feature in iOS 10.

*From the iOS 10 beta 1 release notes:*

> - To improve accessibility on websites in Safari, users can now pinch-to-zoom even when a website sets `user-scalable=no` in the viewport.

I expect we're going to see a JS add-on soon to disable this in some way.

Comment: This is bad... How can we make them change their mind?... why would you get UI designers then when your webapp breaks because of this.

Comment: Why would anything break?   It is a viewport zoom, it is used so users can read webpages on small devices.  It doesn't affect the UI.

Comment: @Onza: I don't think it's bad. I think it's good. Disabling pinch / zooming (default user behaviour) is considered bad, and a lot of mobile websites do it. The only acceptable user case would be a real web app that looks and feels like an app.

Comment: For some reason this causes that when you are clicking buttons it'll zoom, my buttons are the right size, I don't want them to zoom.

Comment: @Onza Buttons shouldn't trigger zoom unless you are double tapping them. Input fields do cause a zoom action when the keyboard and typing cursor appear.

Comment: @Onza If you have a button that requires multiple taps in short intervals you can use javascript to catch the touch events.

Comment: Bad.. I change viewport using js and block zoom only when some elements are selected on the website now it is broken due to this "decision". If someone decide to block it - there is a reason.

Comment: @Karlth it's very bed for a game developer

Comment: @Sandeep Why? (I'm a part time game developer).  If the user decides to zoom into a part of the screen, why would that affect the game?  It might affect his gameplay but not the code - it is just zooming handled by the device. It is just like taking a magnifying glass from a book reader - it doesn't change anything.

Comment: This is outdated. See Cellanes answer. iOS 10 now does support user-scalable=no

Comment: I have IOS 10.0.2, user-scalable=no does not disable zooming anymore on our website... Our main issue with zooming is with our fixed side menu.. It just breaks the layout.. Any ideas or solutions on this? I understand zooming is good for accessibility, we made zooming available on specific parts of our site using js events (hammer) & css.. I don't see why a rule has to be imposed on everyone, seems like the PC Police is starting to take over our dev world as well?!

Comment: "The only acceptable user case would be a real web app that looks and feels like an app." - and this is, like you said, a real, acceptable use case, that isn't *that* rare..

Comment: For "apps" we should be able to prevent double-tap to zoom. Double tap occurs *unintentionally* for normal users e.g. tapping a + button twice, tapping a list item twice. Note that the double-tap zoom also re-introduces the 300ms delay between touchend and click (fixed in iOS9 and broken again in iOS10 - a non-zoomable page in iOS9 has zero delay and iOS10 adds that delay back in again - arrgh!). Accessability is fine if pinch to zoom allowed. Focusing an input with a small font size causing automatic zoom is also sensible for accessability. Double-tap zoom *breaks* accessability for tremors.

Comment: I have an web app that I want to look & feel like a "real app" -- and this Safari ignore-ence (pun intended) completely messes the UX up. What a dumb move on Safari's part.

Comment: @webkit On of the reason it breaks layout is because after zooming in window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight change (while document width / height remain the same) and fixed elements got repositioned to new window size. This occured till iOS 10.2, in new update iOS 10.3, this "feature" is dropped and fixed elements are aligned to document, not zoom-adjusted window size.

Still we need to take care of touch events (e.g. intercepted by hammer) though. It's probably best to just disable all swipe / pan / pinch events (like galleries) when window is zoomed-in to allow user pan zoomed-in site.

Comment: They should have made this an option in the accessibility menu, so it's still an option but for the other 99% of the users not the default behaviour.

Comment: @DirkBoer I have to disagree with you. Apple is trying to make their products appealing for everyone. This includes people with poor-sight, a huge portion of them are the elderly. Those people rely on the it-just-works-out-of-the-box'ness of the devices. These are not people that are going to find the "allow me to zoom everywhere" feature. People with niche disabilities know to search for help-me features, those are the ones you find in Accessibility. - From Apple's perspective, I understand why they did it this way. - Is what I'm trying to say.

Comment: Hi Paul, I understand what you're saying. I think it's rather arbitrary though, because all 'navtive' apps won't zoom in anyway if you don't go to the accesibility menu explicitly.

Comment: @DirkBoer well-implemented apps scale with the system-font size slider if I'm not mistaken. But again, then why not just decrease the perceived screen width in the browser if we increase the font-size (effectively scaling-up the website's UI). Responsive sites should be able to handle abuse like this. That seems like a nice solution to me anyway.

Comment: @DirkBoer System-font size slider is very easy to find since it is (almost) accessible from the main settings page. Pinching is also something we expect to work in the browser, because it usually does. So the fact that it would suddenly not work could be considered confusing behaviour.

Comment: It's bad for map applications where pinch zooming is important.

Answer (score 27):

I've been able to fix this using the [`touch-action`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action) css property on individual elements. Try setting `touch-action: manipulation;` on elements that are commonly clicked on, like links or buttons.

Comment: "manipulation" doesn't prevent pinch zoom, only double-tap zoom.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. you can use `touch-action: none;` to control all the gestures yourself.

Comment: this is great - disabling double-tap zooming while leaving pinch zooming, which SHOULD be considered a gesture - double tapping should not. 1 dog is a dog. 1 dog + 1 dog does not a space shuttle make. It makes 2 dogs, and they do things that you'd expect 2 dogs to do. I have never expected 2 dogs to be a space shuttle. Never.

Comment: @GuySopher iOS does *not* provide `touch-action: none` only `manipulatoin`, which leaves the pinch-zoom problem as it is.

Comment: use touch-action: pan-x pan-y, fixes it.

Answer (score 27):

The workaround that works in Mobile Safari at this time of writing, is to have the the third argument in `addEventListener` be `{ passive: false }`, so the full workaround looks like this:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
  if (event.scale !== 1) { event.preventDefault(); }
}, { passive: false });
```

You may want to [check if options are supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Safely_detecting_option_support) to remain backwards compatible.

Comment: Thank you. I spent hours looking for something that actually worked. This combined with making my 3d canvas fixed position solved it!

Comment: Anyone tried this on iOS 12? I added the above code and it is doing nothing for my webapp. Still able to zoom in this stupid Safari. My meta viewport tag looks like this btw: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`.

Comment: @PatrickDaVader Yep, can't find any working solution for iOS 12 Safari. Getting seasick from all the incessant zooming.

Comment: This one works in iOS 13. My <meta> tags include: ```<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />``` and ```<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">```

Comment: This works in iOS 12.3.1. My <meta> tag is: `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />`

Comment: @SterlingBourne Copied your setup. Does work, but only like 90% of the time. Not sure why not all the time.

Comment: @Hillcow: I ended up needing to use a Node Module to 100% get this to work: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-scroll-lock

Comment: @SterlingBourne response worked for me! Thanks. He should post it as an answer rather than a comment so it can be voted

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" /> and <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">

Comment: Note that this will prevent any touchmove action that doesn't have a scale property, if you still want to do things like support touch scroll of some elements you need to check ```if (event.scale !== undefined && event.scale !== 1) { event.preventDefault(); }```

Answer (score 23):

Use "touch-action: pan-x pan-y" to disable "pinch zoom" as well as "double tap zoom". It works on all touch screens / phones I have tested including iOS Safari 14.5.1.

```css
body {
  touch-action: pan-x pan-y;
}
```

Comment: Best answer nowadays. It works perfectly.

Comment: Its' not working on scrollable element but working on non-scrollable element, what is scaleable solution to avoid this issue for scrollable element

Comment: Flawless on iOS 15

Comment: In addition to `body`, you also need to set this on any element that has `overflow: scroll` or `overflow: auto`. Or just set it on `*`.

Answer (score 15):

It appears that this behavior is supposedly changed in the latest beta, which at the time of writing is beta 6.

From the release notes for iOS 10 Beta 6:

> `WKWebView` now defaults to respecting `user-scalable=no` from a viewport.
>   Clients of `WKWebView` can improve accessibility and allow users to
>   pinch-to-zoom on all pages by setting the `WKWebViewConfiguration`
>   property `ignoresViewportScaleLimits` to `YES`.

However, in my (very limited) testing, I can't yet confirm this to be the case.

Edit: verified, iOS 10 Beta 6 respects `user-scalable=no` by default for me.

Comment: 10.0.1 here. Does not respect it. What is with Apple getting rid of features that everyone needs..

Comment: This refers to `WKWebView` **not** to Safari. Source: One of our map apps broke and we have *no* idea how to fix it.

Comment: Aha! Apologies, I came here when searching for solution for the same bug/feature in `WKWebView` and kind of assumed that the original question asked about `WKWebView` when writing my answer.

So I suppose that during one of the first beta versions, Apple changed the behavior of both `WKWebView` and mobile Safari, then in beta 6, they reverted the behavior of `WKWebView` but kept it for the mobile Safari.

Comment: 10.0.2 does not respect `user-scalable=no`. I'm not sure why they would ever undo this, only to bring it back, only to remove it again.

Answer (score 8):

I spent about an hour looking for a more robust javascript option, and did not find one.  It just so happens that in the past few days I've been fiddling with [hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/) (Hammer.js is a library that lets you manipulate all sorts of touch events easily) and mostly failing at what I was trying to do.

With that caveat, and understanding I am by no means a javascript expert, this is a solution I came up with that basically leverages hammer.js to capture the pinch-zoom and double-tap events and then log and discard them.

Make sure you include hammer.js in your page and then try sticking this javascript in the head somewhere:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" src="http://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.min.js"> < /script >
< script type = "text/javascript" >

  // SPORK - block pinch-zoom to force use of tooltip zoom
  $(document).ready(function() {

    // the element you want to attach to, probably a wrapper for the page
    var myElement = document.getElementById('yourwrapperelement');
    // create a new hammer object, setting "touchAction" ensures the user can still scroll/pan
    var hammertime = new Hammer(myElement, {
      prevent_default: false,
      touchAction: "pan"
    });

    // pinch is not enabled by default in hammer
    hammertime.get('pinch').set({
      enable: true
    });

    // name the events you want to capture, then call some function if you want and most importantly, add the preventDefault to block the normal pinch action
    hammertime.on('pinch pinchend pinchstart doubletap', function(e) {
      console.log('captured event:', e.type);
      e.preventDefault();
    })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I've also been trying to solve this problem when working with hammer.js, and can confirm that I could prevent the viewport zoom by adding a `.preventDefault` to all the hammer gesture handlers.  I'm using swipe/pinch/pan/tap together, i've added it to all the handlers, i don't know whether there's a specific one that's doing the job.

Answer (score 8):

In my particular case, I am using Babylon.js to create a 3D scene and my whole page consists of one full screen canvas. The 3D engine has its own zooming functionality but on iOS the pinch-to-zoom interferes with that. I updated the the @Joseph answer to overcome my problem. To disable it, I figured out that I need to pass the {passive: false} as an option to the event listener. The following code works for me:

```
window.addEventListener(
    "touchmove",
    function(event) {
        if (event.scale !== 1) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    },
    { passive: false }
);
```

Comment: My use case is also a full page 3d scene with custom pinch controls. I would have been sunk if there wasn't a workaround to Apple explicitly ignoring the user-scale: no meta.

Comment: Life-saver - This is the only solution that works for me as of iOS 14.4.2 that still allows for multi-touch being registered - My use-case being a web game that uses joystick controls for mobile.

Answer (score 7):

We can get everything we want by injecting one style rule and by intercepting zoom events:

```
$(function () {
  if (!(/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent))) return
  $(document.head).append(
    '<style>*{cursor:pointer;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)}</style>'
  )
  $(window).on('gesturestart touchmove', function (evt) {
    if (evt.originalEvent.scale !== 1) {
      evt.originalEvent.preventDefault()
      document.body.style.transform = 'scale(1)'
    }
  })
})
```

✔ Disables pinch zoom.

✔ Disables double-tap zoom.

✔ Scroll is not affected.

✔ Disables tap highlight (which is triggered, on iOS, by the style rule).

NOTICE: Tweak the iOS-detection to your liking. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038625/detect-if-device-is-ios).

---

Apologies to **lukejackson** and **Piotr Kowalski**, whose answers appear in modified form in the code above.

Comment: This works on my iPad emulator which is running iOS 11.2. On my real iPad running iOS 11.3 it doesn't work.

I added a console.log to make sure the events are fired and so they appear in the console.

It is something to do with iOS 11.3 ? Or with real devices ?

Comment: @MathieuR. It is an iOS 11.3 issue. It can be rectified by using one of the `addEventListener` based answers and  passing `{ passive: false }` as the `options` parameter instead of `false`. However, for backward compatibility you need to pass `false` unless the `passive` option field is supported. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Improving_scrolling_performance_with_passive_listeners

Comment: @JoshGallagher Could you provide a working example? On iOS11 none of the answers is working for me.

Comment: The 'gesturestart' -> preventDefault works for me at time of writing on iOS 12,2

Answer (score 6):

I tried the previous answer about pinch-to-zoom

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('touchstart', function (event) {
    if (event.touches.length > 1) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

however sometime the screen still zoom when the  **event.touches.length > 1**
I found out the best way is using touchmove event, to avoid any finger moving on the screen. The code will be something like this:

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();      
}, false);
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: This works only if your app is a perfect fit... if you do have scrollable content  it doesn't works... still nice hack for some scenarios.

Comment: This even disables scroll on website.. BAD

Comment: @eljamz thanks for let me know and yes..my app is perfect fit on screen.

Comment: @Gags I didn't test the scroll function yet, thanks for let me know.

Answer (score 6):

Check for scale factor in touchove event then prevent touch event.

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
    event = event.originalEvent || event;
    if(event.scale > 1) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: iOS 13 change false to {passive: false}

Answer (score 6):

I came up with a pretty naive solution, but it seems to work.
My goal was to prevent accidental double-taps to be interpreted as zoom in, while keeping pinch to zoom working for accessibility.

The idea is in measuring time between the first `touchstart` and second `touchend` in a double tap and then interpreting the last `touchend` as click if the delay is too small. While preventing accidental zooming, this method seems to keep list scrolling unaffected, which is nice. Not sure if I haven't missed anything though.

```
let preLastTouchStartAt = 0;
let lastTouchStartAt = 0;
const delay = 500;

document.addEventListener('touchstart', () => {
  preLastTouchStartAt = lastTouchStartAt;
  lastTouchStartAt = +new Date();
});
document.addEventListener('touchend', (event) => {
  const touchEndAt = +new Date();
  if (touchEndAt - preLastTouchStartAt < delay) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.target.click();
  }
});
```

Inspired by a [gist from mutewinter](https://gist.github.com/mutewinter/b86fc06bae43fd3e13169bfb569b06b1) and [Joseph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38573198/1818285).

Answer (score 5):

As requested, I have transfered my comment to an answer so people can upvote it:

This works 90% of the time for iOS 13:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />`

and

`<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">`

Comment: Why does this work 90% of the time? I tried it on mine and didn't work :(

Comment: @JeanPaulA. You're part of the 10% then

Answer (score 1):

As odd as it sounds, at least for Safari in iOS 10.2, double tap to zoom is magically disabled if your element or any of its ancestors have one of the following:

1. An onClick listener - it can be a simple noop.
2. A `cursor: pointer` set in CSS

Comment: how about pinching?

Comment: Unfortunately, pinch to zoom is not covered by this solution.
For that, we used the solution proposed in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39594334/374196

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I am using 10.2.1 Beta 4 on an iPod Touch using this test page and double tapping any of the grey squares zooms: https://jsbin.com/kamuta/quiet

Comment: I have this on a span in a react app and it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Unintentional *zooming* tends to happen when:

- A user double taps on a component of the interface
- A user interacts with the viewport using two or more digits (pinch)

To prevent the *double tap* behaviour I have found two very simple workarounds:

```
<button onclick='event.preventDefault()'>Prevent Default</button>
<button style='touch-action: manipulation'>Touch Action Manipulation</button>
```

Both of these prevent Safari (iOS 10.3.2) from *zooming* in on the button. As you can see one is JavaScript only, the other is CSS only. Use appropriately.

Here is a demo: https://codepen.io/lukejacksonn/pen/QMELXQ

I have not attempted to prevent the pinch behaviour (yet), primarily because I tend not to create multi touch interfaces for the web and secondly I have come round to the idea that perhaps all interfaces including native app UI should be "pinch to zoom"-able in places. I'd still design to avoid the user *having* to do this to make your UI accessible to them, at all costs.

Answer (score 1):

Found this simple work around which appears to prevent double click to zoom:

```
    // Convert touchend events to click events to work around an IOS 10 feature which prevents
    // developers from using disabling double click touch zoom (which we don't want).
    document.addEventListener('touchend', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(event.target).trigger('click');
    }, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of safari this is not working anymore. You have to define the second parameter as non-passive by passing {passiv:false}

```
 document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
}, { passive: false });
```

Comment: Tested on iOS 14.4 :  it disables touch scrolling of the viewport so you cannot scroll the page up and down anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I checked all above answers in practice with my page on iOS (iPhone 6, iOS 10.0.2), but with no success. This is my working solution:

```
$(window).bind('gesturestart touchmove', function(event) {
    event = event.originalEvent || event;
    if (event.scale !== 1) {
         event.preventDefault();
         document.body.style.transform = 'scale(1)'
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only works when your page is a perfect fit, not when you have scrollable content

Comment: Hmm. This works fine with scrollable content, in my experience (iOS 10.3).

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Comment: I tried this, it did prevent pinch zooming, however it disables touch scrolling of the viewport so you cannot scroll the page up and down anymore.