# Blueimp: zoom on mobile and unwanted blue selection highlight on android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, blueimp

I use the blueimp gallery on this website: https://www.bestofcinqueterre.com/en/manarola

But I have 2 problems:

1. Zoom on mobile breaks everything. To fix it - I disable zoomin in viewport only when gallery is opened and then enable zooming when it is closed. But after ios10 release it's not possible to block zooming anymore. So if someone opens a photo on mobile and zoom - strange things happens.
2. When I click "Next" photo on Android all screen is highlighted. I've tried to fix it adding:
   preventDefault + stopPropagation when the button is clicked.
   Added this to css:

> ```
> button, button:hover, li:hover, a:hover , li , a , *:hover, *
> {
> -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
> -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
> }
> ```
>
> It doesn't help...

Comment: hey nice site! Apparently the recent version of ios 10 respects zoom=no ? there are a couple of answers and hacks over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808180/disable-viewport-zooming-ios-10-safari . it's difficult to help with the second question as it appears to work fine on my android, running the chrome browser. which browser is it not working in for you? firefox? if it's the 'stock' android browser and not chrome then there might not be much you can do - there are manby things it doesn't support, and it is being replaced by chrome in anycase so should soon be a rare use case.

Comment: @Sam0 thank you, I've added a code to disable zoom when gallery is opened for ios10, will check it with Android too (my tablet for tests just broke today)