# How to disable pinch2zoom on webpages on iOS 10 Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari

It seems that:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`

… has stopped working on mobile Safari after the iOS 10 update.

Is there a way to disable pinch2zoom again?

> Please do not respond with "don't do this, outdated accessibility gyan and how the scroll has worked for web" because you don't understand my users or my needs, and I don't want this thread to become yet another flamewar between old school web developers and the new generation.

I'm happy to use JavaScript to disable pinch2zoom sitewide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `tap` event:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', event => {
  if (event.scale !== 1) { event.preventDefault() }
}, false)
```

For `doubletap` event:

```
let lastTouchEnd = 0;
document.addEventListener('touchend', event => {
  const now = (new Date()).getTime()
  if (now - lastTouchEnd <= 300) event.preventDefault()
  lastTouchEnd = now
}, false)
```

Explanation is given on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808180/disable-viewport-zooming-ios-10-safari).