# How to disable viewport zooming iOS 10 safari?

Tags: safari

Below code is not working in safari ios 10 mobiles.

```
meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'
```

Actually i want disable pinch to zoom in ios 10 mobile phones safari browser. How to solve?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808180/disable-viewport-zooming-ios-10-safari

Answer (score 0):

Insert this into the head tag -

`<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`

However it does not work on devices with ios 10 onwards.