# User-Scalable meta attribute not working

Tags: html, viewport, zooming

I tried to use "user-scalable=no" in the meta tag to disable zooming my webpage. I tested it and the webpage was zoomed in. How can I make it the original but still disable zooming? I also tried initial-scale=1.0 doesnt work though. So what do I have to put in the meta tag do disable zooming but with the original size?
thanks in advance

Comment: What browser(s) on which operating system(s) are you testing this with?

Comment: I've tested it on a android mobile phone using chrome. I just think its weird that when I only use user-scalable=no the page automatically zooms in

Comment: If you're using iOS 10, this feature has been disabled. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37859168/1268350

Comment: @HemantArora but with javascript i can still disable zooming right?

Comment: Yes. It will work on all platforms except iOS 10 and later.

Comment: hello. Disabling user-scalable is an accessibility issue. Do not do this :)

Comment: Hello,. Enabling user-scalable is also an accessibility issue. I.E. i makes your app completely inaccessible when safari starts zooming and panning when other gestures are clearly intended.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy way workable solution yet (as of moment of writing this). iOS simple ignores user-scalable.
Btw, this seems like duplicated question. Please see : 
[disable viewport zooming iOS 10+ safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808180/disable-viewport-zooming-ios-10-safari)