# How to control zoom level in iPad, Tab, etc

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, zooming, pinchzoom

I have created an application which will work only on limit zoom level. So I need to restrict that user can zoom the limited level.

I have tried with,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

But it always allows upto the device.

Comment: Have you tried to add **user-scalable=no** ?

Comment: I have tried this. But still browser allows more zoom.

Comment: Oh i see, if you using Safari on iOS 10+: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37859168/4769339
`To improve accessibility on websites in Safari, users can now pinch-to-zoom even when a website sets user-scalable=no in the viewport.`

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust your media query to prevent zooming

try this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: I have tried  this. But still browser allows more zoom.