# Disable zoom on websites for iOS 12+

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, gesture

I am looking now for days for a working code to disable the iOS zoom for websites.

I also found this:
[disable viewport zooming iOS 10+ safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808180/disable-viewport-zooming-ios-10-safari)

The fixes may work for iOS 10 but seems not to work for iOS 12. I already found a website where the zoom is disabled successfully but I am not able to find out how they have done it.

I know that Apple removed the possibility to disable the zoom via viewport-meta tag but there must be a workaround to disable it for a website.

For our website its essential that the zoom is disabled or that the zoom does not trigger a resize event. Any ideas how to solve this?

What I have tried already is e.g. to prevent touchmove / ontouchstart / gesturestart ... nothing of them worked.

Comment: Same problem here, can u send me the website url?

Comment: Sorry @Animan - too much time is gone until then. I can not remember which site it was.

Comment: Hi @TJR did you find solution to this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [disable Double tap zoom/resize on safari IOS12\*\*\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56024398/disable-double-tap-zoom-resize-on-safari-ios12)

Answer (score 0):

Double tap zoom can be disabled by adding an empty click event listener on your elements.

Disabling pinch to zoom is a pain, you have to prevent touchstart event if event.touches > 1, but this only works when page is not momentum scrolling

[See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56393464/3089199).