# Disable pinch / zoom in IOS Safari while being in fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-safari

I have a webgl game working fine on iPad Safari
I can disable system pinch / zoom actions with usual solutions (like this one: [disable viewport zooming iOS 10+ safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808180/disable-viewport-zooming-ios-10-safari))
But I can't get any to work after the game is switched to fullscreen with `document.body.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT)`

I have `touch-action: none;`, `user-scalable=no` in meta, `passive: false` and `e.preventDefault();` for all touch events (touchstart, touchend, touchmove, touchcancel)

Edit: here's a codepen with most things I've tried: https://codepen.io/SerialF/pen/BaaRKJN

Comment: i have the same problem and i have been searching the solution for months

Comment: I still haven't found any solution either :(
No answer [on three.js forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/problems-with-running-3d-web-apps-games-on-iphones/9468)

Answer (score 0):

Have you made any progress on this? I am running into a similar issue with a three.js built on angular application. Can't figure out how to disable the exit full screen on an ipad in safari when pinch-zoom-out. I found that Chrome doesn't support full screen on ipad, I tried disabling touch events, e.preventDefault() on a touchstart listener. I can not find where the exitFullScreen is being called, seems like it's just built into the OS and is completely independent from the DOM.

UPDATE: Not a 100% solution but thanks to Florent for bringing this workaround to my attention.

"They do suggest to add a shortcut to home screen, as with all the required PWA meta-tags (see [here](https://medium.com/appscope/designing-native-like-progressive-web-apps-for-ios-1b3cdda1d0e8)), this is the only way to have fullscreen working properly"

Comment: No, never found any solution. My games don't use fullscreen on ios, it's unusable. They do suggest to add a shortcut to home screen, as with all the required PWA meta-tags (see [here](https://medium.com/appscope/designing-native-like-progressive-web-apps-for-ios-1b3cdda1d0e8)), this is the only way to have fullscreen working properly.